# Move folder into a new git project adding parent folder as submodule

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have been working on the git repository `projectA`. After some work, I realised that my changes do not fit entirely in the scope of this project and I want to separate a new folder I created into a new git repo, while adding what remains to `projectA` as a submodule in the new repo.

The current folder structure is

```
projectA
├── build
├── executables
├── lib
├── *projectB*
│   ├── *subfolders from project B*
│   └── ....
├── resources
├── src
└── test
```

What I would like to to is moving the entire `*projectB*` folder into a new GitHub repo. Since `projectB` depends on some targets defined in other folders of `projectA`, I think that the easiest solution would be to have

```
projectB
├── lib
│   └── *projectA*
└── subfolders from project B
    ├── ....
    └── ....
```

where `projectA` is now a git submodule.

Is there a clean, fast, and possibly semi-automated way of achieving this, to avoid screwing up my git repos?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `projectA` has branch `main`. To separate the history of `projectB` from the current repository,

```
git checkout -b b_main main
git filter-branch -f --subdirectory-filter projectB
```

Now `b_main` is the branch that has `projectB` as its root. If you checkout `b_main`, you will see files and folders under the previous `projectB`.

Remove the history of `projectB` from the history of `projectA`.

```
git checkout -b a_main main
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm -rf projectB'
```

Now `a_main` does not have `projectB` as if it has never existed. Push `a_main` to replace the previous `main` in the remote repository of `projectA`.

```
git push origin -f a_main:main
```

Switch to `b_main` and add the new `main` of `projectA` as a submodule.

```
git checkout b_main
git submodule add -b main <repo_url_to_projectA>
git commit
```

Push `b_main` to the new repository as its `main`.

```
git push <repo_url_to_projectB> b_main:main
```

Clone the new `projectB` to check if it's okay.

```
git clone --recurse-submodules <repo_url_to_projectB> -b main
```